# Python CGI/RE Help Needed

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, cgi, forms

I understand most of the following code and what it does except for the `if re.search(str(searchString), line) != None:`  line - which is near the bottom.

The code accepts a string input by the user on another HTML form and then this python script runs to check a file if the entered string/words is in that file and then prints all lines with the word in.

```
import cgi, re

print ('Content-type: text/html \n')
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('<title>Web Client Server File Search Example </title>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ("<H1>Search Text Example </H1>")

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
searchString = form.getvalue('search')   
print("<br><H2 style='color:red;'> Search String: ", searchString)
fh = open("animals.txt")
fhdatalist = fh.readlines()

for line in fhdatalist:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search(str(searchString), line) != None:
        print ('<br>Line Found: ', line)

fh.close()
```

Could someone briefly explain how it/the search() works please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchString = form.getvalue('search')
```

this line takes the search value entered in a form on the HTML page

```
if re.search(str(searchString), line) != None:
```

this line takes each line in the animals.txt file and checks if the search word is found in that line. If it's found, that line from animals.txt is printed.

re is the python regular expression parser, which is extremely powerful and you should check it out!

Python2.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Python3.5: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

======

And now, a word of warning. You are letting the viewer of your web page interact directly with your code. What if I searched for the following terms? Try it and see what happens:

```
.*
*
```

Comment: Okay thanks! That makes more sense I think. What is the '!= None:' part for then?

Comment: When the re.search function finds a match, it returns a match object, that you can get info from. If it doesn't find anything, it returns `None`. 

So, that line is saying "if the re.search functions return value does not equal `None`, print the line form the file.

That's a slight error by the way - you might want to change the line to `if re.search(str(searchString), line) is not None:`. Your homework is to find out why ;)

Comment: Funnily enough my tutor actually wrote that code...so I thought he'd have done it right! Reading it as 'is not None' makes it easier to understand now. Thank you so much!